# Problem with weird values in DTM and not showing correct elevation

Tags: raster, dem, elevation, terrain

I am still new to Gis and don't know if I understand what is wrong.

I am working in a ocean survey program with point clouds. As seen on the picture the minimum depth is 1,92 and maximum 12,02. I first export the point cloud to a .dtm file. After that I export it as an tif (can't change anything here, only choose the option for which file format to save it in like tif).

The problem is when I look at it in Qgis there are 4 bands created and the maximum and minimum value are all weird (maybe I who can't interpret it). Shouldn't the value of elevation be stored in the cells as 1.92 min and 12.02 and not 248 and 0.
[image: Qgis info]

[image: Navi Model]

Comment: you have exported your data as a picture not as data, those values represent how red (green & blue) your image is.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any option for exporting elevation. On picture 2, are all the options. Thanks for the answer btw.